# Question about complex exponentation

Tags: complex-analysis

We define: $z^w:=e^{wLogz}$ but in general for complex numbers $wLogz \ne Log z^w$. (Even if we take principial branch). So what is the reasoning for it?

Answer (score 2):

Let $Log z$ be the principal branch, and $z=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$. So as you point out $Log z^2=\frac{-2\pi i}{3}\ne 2Log z=\frac{4\pi i}{3}$. However, $e^{Log z^2}=e^{2Log z}=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$.